# How to get the underling data of a MA plot?

Tags: r, limma

I would like to use the [`plotMA`](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/limma/html/plotma.html) function of `limma`.

The example of the documentation works fine:

```
A <- runif(1000,4,16)
y <- A + matrix(rnorm(1000*3,sd=0.2),1000,3)
status <- rep(c(0,-1,1),c(950,40,10))
y[,1] <- y[,1] + status
plotMA(y, array=1, status=status, values=c(-1,1), hl.col=c("blue","red"))
```

Now I would like to access the underlying data that is used for the plot as I would like to use the data in a different context, not just the plot. I currently don't see a way to access the data; of course I could implement the method myself and only use the data, but that feels wrong.

Is there a way to access the underlying data used for the MA plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code of `plotMA` we see that several variables are created and used for plotting. These variables are not returned however.

You could now copy and paste the function to write your own function, which plots and returns the data. This is however, error-prone,if there is a new version of the function you may rely on old code.

So what you can do instead is to use `trace` to insert arbitrary code into `plotMA` notably some code which stores the data in your global environment. I illustrate the idea with a toy example:

```
f <- function(x) {
   y <- x + rnorm(length(x))
   plot(x, y)
   invisible()
}
```

If we would like to use `y` in this function we could do something like this

```
trace(f, exit = quote(my_y <<- y))
# [1] "f"
ls()
# [1] "f"
f(1:10)
# Tracing f(1:10) on exit 
ls()
# [1] "f"    "my_y"
```

And now we can access `my_y`.

**What you should do:**

1. Look at the code of `plotMA`
2. Identify which part of the data you need (e.g. `x`, `y` and `sel`)
3. Use `trace(plotMA, exit = quote({my_data <<- list(x, y, sel)}), where = asNamespace("limma"))`
4. Run `plotMA`
5. Access the data via `my_data`

*Note.*  Check out `?trace` to fully understand the possibilities of it. In particular, if you want to inject your code not at the end (`exit`) but at another psoition (maybe because intermediate variables are overwritten and you need the first results) for which you would need to use the `at` parameter of `trace`

---

**Update**

Maybe the easiest is to get a full dump of all local variables defined in the function:

```
trace("plotMA", exit = quote(var_dump <<- mget(ls())), where = asNamespace("limma"))
```

Comment: Ok, will try this and then get back to you if I succeed (upvote/accept).

Comment: Stupid question but what would be the fastest way to see the source code? I tried `limma::plotMA` and a couple of other options but without success. How did you do it?

Comment: I could not even install library `limma` in the first place, but I looked the code up on [GitHub](https://github.com/cran/limma/blob/master/R/plots-ma.R)

Comment: Reason why I could not install it: `Depends: R (<= 2.5.1)`, which ancient `R` version are you using? :-O

Comment: Ok, that's what I did as well, but not sure whether that is the latest code as it was last changed in 2006.

Comment: I use 3.5.1, works fine. `> packageVersion("limma") [1] ‘3.36.5’`

Comment: I made an update, maybe the safest is to store all local vars in a list and then just take the ones you need

Comment: Tried but did not work, or I use it wrong: `trace("plotMA", exit = quote(var_dump <<- mget(ls())), where = asNamespace("limma"))`. That returns `Tracing function "plotMA" in package "namespace:limma"`. Then I run `plotMA(y, array=1, status=status, values=c(-1,1), hl.col=c("blue","red"))` which plots fine. However, when I then try to access `var_dump` it says `Error: object 'var_dump' not found`. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you calling `plotMA` from the global environment or from within a function?

Comment: global environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191586/discussion-between-thothal-and-cleb).

Comment: `trace("plotMA.default", exit = quote(var_dump <<- mget(ls())), where = asNamespace("limma"))` did the trick, so I needed to use `.default`. Thanks!